# How to use function from other class in entire class or entire project as a global value?

Tags: python

I have a question. I have a Handlers class in `handler.py`, e.g.:

```
class Handlers:
    def my_driver(self):
        my_code_is_here
        ...
        return driver_session
```

In this class is many drivers.

In other `file.py` I have a tests methods, e.g.:

```
class MyTests:
    def add_something(self):
        driver = Handlers.my_driver(self)
        some_code_with_driver...
    def edit_something(self):
        driver = Handlers.my_driver(self)
        some_code_with_driver...
    def delete_something(self):
        driver = Handlers.my_driver(self)
        some_code_with_driver...
```

I want to use this `my_driver` in this file, but to declare it only one time per whole project(`file.py`) or whole class (`MyMethods`), not once per function in class. How can I do it properly? I don't want to use it in main `test.py` file in `setUpClass` as:
`self.driver = Handlers.my_driver(self)` because each tests uses different driver.

Comment: which testing u are using or it is just random class?

Comment: Random. Eg. in my ```test.py``` i'm using this methods from ```file.py```.

Comment: Make a decorator to populate method with driver if you mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use your own testing class.

```
class MyTests:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handler=Handlers()
    
    def add_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
    def edit_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
    def delete_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
```

if you use for example TestCase then

```
class MyTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.handler=Handlers()
    
    def add_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
    def edit_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
    def delete_something(self):
        driver = self.handler.my_driver()
        some_code_with_driver...
```

Comment: In your first example I have a Attribute Error:  ```AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'handler'```

Comment: which testing tool you are using?

Comment: Unittest. Ok, second example works fine, but without ```self``` in ```my_driver()``` in functions :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The downside of this approach is that tests now running slower when you declare ```self.handler=Handlers()``` instead of ```self.handler=Handlers.my_driver(self)``` in ```setUpClass```. Either way, thanks for the quick help!